# Retrieving build number of a resolved artifact

Tags: gradle, artifactory

We are using the gradle artifactory plugin to publish a jar to artifactory. And for publishing, a build number is also given.

Artifactory lists the jar for the build number fine.

Now I have a gradle script where I am retrieving the latest version of the jar file. It is working fine. I am using getResolvedArtifacts() and I get the jar properly. Now I also want to know the build number associated with that version in artifactory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse it but you can do:

```
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.each { println it }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally ended up doing a GET call on the api/storage/xxx?properties=build.version on the full versioned url of the artifact. Looks like gradle resolvedArtifact() doesn't have an option to get build properties from artifactory.